# windows npm install couchbase msbuild error code 1

Tags: visual-studio, npm, installation, couchbase

Environment - Windows 7 Enterprise (Service Pack 1)

Process

installed git

configured user.name and user.email for git

installed nodejs

```
node version - 8.11.3

npm version - 6.4.0
```

installed Python 2.7.3

```
added environement variable and updated path statement
```

installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Version

```
installed Visual C== 2015 Tools for Windows Desktop

installed Windows XP Support for C++
```

installed node-gyp (both locally and globally)

```
 npm config --global set msvs_version=2015
```

set environment variable `GYP_MSVS_VERSION` to 2015

installed couchbase server (4.5)

After all this setup I attempt to perform npm install couchbase.

After process I receive the following error:

> prebuild verb onExit
>
> prebuild ERR! build error
>
> prebuild ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1 signal
>   null
>
> prebuild ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\AJS\Nexcal
>
> Development\nexcal\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
>
> prebuild ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>
> prebuild ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>
> prebuild ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>
> (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>
> prebuild ERR! not ok
>
> prebuild ERR! build Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1 signal
>   null
>
> prebuild ERR! build     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\AJS\Nexcal
>
> Development\nexcal\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
>
> prebuild ERR! build     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>
> prebuild ERR! build     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>
> prebuild ERR! build     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
>   (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>
> npm WARN grunt-mocha-test@0.12.7 requires a peer of mocha@>=1.20.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 2
>
> npm ERR! couchbase@2.2.3 install: `prebuild --install`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the couchbase@2.2.3 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     npm-cache_logs\2018-08-16T13_36_46_122Z-debug.log

i have re-installed nodejs, python, node-gyp, couchbase server, installed/uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 Professional and Visual Studio community, I cannot get the Couchbase Node.js SDK libraries to install.  Can you suggest an alternative to loading the SDK?

TIA
AnthonyS

Comment: I eventually resolved the issue.  Instead of running npm install couchbase, I ran npm install "git+https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode.git#master"

Comment: So this issue has been resolved in your side, am I right? If so, would you please share your solution as an answer? And then accept/mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members directly.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this issue, I ran git+github.com/couchbase/couchbase.git#master instead of npm install couchbase.